# React Native - Picker -- Multiple wheels parallel

Tags: javascript, react-native, picker

I am using the following package for displaying a Picker in my react native application: (https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker)

I am using the date picker element, where I get todays current date and the starting year/month/day is todays day.

So for example, on load it would show "2016 12  02"

However, when someone selects something like "2017" then it the months/days will revert back to normal as these dates are in the future.

The issue that I'm having is that when I change the date, the month and day scoll back to the selected value. I have implemented the following code:

```
<Picker
   ref={datePicker => this.datePicker = datePicker}
   style={styles.colorPicker}
   pickerData={this.createDateData()}
   selectedValue={[this.state.selectedYear, '12', '12']}
   onPickerDone={(pickedValue) => {
     var date = pickedValue[2] + '/' + pickedValue[1] + '/' + pickedValue[0];
     this.setState({datepicker_enabled: true});
     this.setState({date: date});
   }}

   onValueChange={(value) => {
     this.changeDateWheel(value[0]);
   }}
/>
```

The issue seems to be with the `selectedValue` as when the wheel changes, it will automatically go back to default values. I can't seem to use the `Picker` without default values.

In the read.me on github the documentation states:

> Notice
>
> support two modes:
>
> 1. parallel: such as time picker, wheels have no connection with each other
> 2. cascade: such as date picker, address picker .etc, when front wheel changed, the behind wheels will all be reset

But I cannot figure out how to use the Parallel for this.

Comment: Hi @Phorce
I know it's late, but you shouldn't use the parallel mode for a date picker, because e.g. months/days depend on the year, so I would always say that it is desirable to reset the wheels to the right of a wheel when it changes (assuming left-to-right reading direction). Just as the documentation you pasted says.